# CSS Box Shadow Bottom Only

Tags: css, underline, box-shadow

How can I do this? I want my element to look as though it has a shadow underline. I don't want the shadow for the other 3 sides.

Comment: Try also [**this method**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24698566/1677209) if you have monochromatic background

Answer (score 1136, accepted):

Do this:

```
box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px gray;
```

It's actually much simpler, whatever you set the blur to (3rd value), set the spread (4th value) to the negative of it.

Comment: This is by far the best method. Pure css3, no hacks.

Comment: Just in case anyone wants to understand why this works:
* The first value sets the x-offset of the light source to 0.
* The second value sets y-offset of the light source to +4.
* The third value sets a blur effects of 2px. (Makes the shadow non-uniform).
* The fourth value sets a spread to -2px. (Contract the shadow 2px.)

This will cause the shadow to be 4px less wide than the element you're shadowing, so set the last value to 0 if you just want a plain underline.

Comment: It doesn't worked for me under firefox 18.X. What worked for me was: `box-shadow: inset 0 -4px 3px black;` But it also generates a little shadow on the sides.. :_(

Comment: however it does not work good for big (20px or more) shadows... :(

Comment: Similar to @elboletaire's solution, this worked for me: `box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);`

Comment: This is a more realistic shadow example for left only or left and right : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20596554/1491212
Can be adapted to suit your needs.

Comment: why does the first number not have a `px` ?

Comment: @gwho - 0 is 0, regardless of the units, so adding 'px' is redundant. You can safely put 'px' after the zero (or 'pt' or '%' or any valid units) if you want.

Comment: so the choice to omit one here, and include one there was just arbitrary. good to know, thanks!

Comment: When using this under firefox, there will be a very slim line around the box that gets the shadow. You can fix this by increasing the spread to -3px instead of -2px, which of course reduces the bottom shadow some.

Comment: Hey OP, how about selecting this post as accepted answer?

Comment: @ahnbizcad Not fully arbitrary. `0` doesn't need a unit. Hence, adding a unit is redundant and wasting space. Not adding a unit is thus preferable. *However*: I often do add a unit to easy *changing* the value in the Object Inspector... But that's more of a debugging feature...  My guess would be that most minifiers will drop the unit if the value is `0`.

Comment: How about doing it just for the top, or left, or right sides ? Are there any such examples? Or what if you want all but top?

Comment: how about inner shadow?

Comment: it's too small.

Answer (score 60):

You can use two elements, one inside the other, and give the outer one `overflow: hidden` and a width equal to the inner element together with a bottom padding so that the shadow on all the other sides are "cut off"

```
#outer {
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#outer > div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: orange;

    -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

Alternatively, float the outer element to cause it to shrink to the size of the inner element. See: http://jsfiddle.net/QJPd5/1/

Comment: This solution is fantastic if you have to show the shadow for all the window-size.

Comment: This is a solution that fits better the requirements of the question. It really spans the full bottom of the element. While, from my experience, the answer maked as correct displays a shadow slightly shorter than the bottom.

Answer (score 28):

Try this

```
-moz-box-shadow:0 5px 5px rgba(182, 182, 182, 0.75);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(182, 182, 182, 0.75);
box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(182, 182, 182, 0.75);
```

You can see it in http://jsfiddle.net/wJ7qp/

Comment: Working fine for me with 20px `0 20px 20px`

Answer (score 12):

try this to get the box-shadow under your full control.

```
    <html>

    <head>
        <style> 
            div {
                width:300px;
                height:100px;
                background-color:yellow;
                box-shadow: 0 10px black inset,0 -10px red inset, -10px 0 blue inset, 10px 0 green inset;
           }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
        </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

this would apply to outer box-shadow as well.

Comment: How to get blur with this technique ?

Comment: Bottom box shadow with blur:  `box-shadow: 0 -6px 7px -7px grey inset;`