# How to add a box shadow to a table tr element upon hover?

Tags: html, css

So I am attempting to add a box shadow to my table `tr` element upon hover.

Currently, it is working perfectly in Firefox, but no other browser.

**CSS:**

```
table tbody tr:hover {
    background-color:#13326b;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-shadow: 1px 2px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ff0000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ff0000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ff0000;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<table class="table table-list-search">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Logo</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Symbol</th>
                <th>Sector</th>
                <th>Sub-Sector</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Sample</td>
                <td>Filter</td>
                <td>12-11-2011 11:11</td>
                <td>OK</td>
                <td>123</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Try</td>
                <td>It</td>
                <td>11-20-2013 08:56</td>
                <td>It</td>
                <td>Works</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>§</td>
                <td>$</td>
                <td>%</td>
                <td>&</td>
                <td>/</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**Here is an image of how it displays in Firefox:**

[image]

**Here is an image of how it displays in Chrome:**

[image]

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gx7Uy/)

How could I edit my CSS to apply this box shadow hover for all browsers?

Comment: Adding `display: block` to the tr may work in some cases, but is not ideal. Try adding style to `tr:hover td` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is your css i edited

```
table { 
   box-sizing: border-box; 
   border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8; 
}
table tbody tr:hover {
   background-color:#13326b;
   color:#ffffff;
   text-shadow: 1px 2px #000000;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ff0000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ff0000;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ff0000;
}
 td, th { 
    padding-left: 16px; 
    min-width: 170px; 
    text-align: left; 
}
tr { 
    display: block; 
}
table tbody tr , table tbody td{
    height:100px;
}
```

Here is demo link
- http://jsfiddle.net/Gx7Uy/6/

Comment: Works well, although it seems to disrupt the layout of the table heading

Comment: Shortly  tr{ display: block}  -> It is a remedy and a problem, the td,th block tries to mimic the normal array

Comment: display block on the table row causes all the reasons to actually use a table brake. Might as well use div's in the first place.

Comment: Unfortunately, if we will add background color for all <tr> elements then this solution won't work

Answer (score -9):

try something like this,[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Gx7Uy/8/)

```
tr { display: block; }
```

For explanation check this out

[Box Shadow on table row not appearing on certain browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874985/box-shadow-on-table-row-not-appearing-in-chrome)

Comment: As stated to user1153551, `display block` disrupts the entire tables layout.

Comment: Who voted up? This is totally bad response!