# Background color hiding other box-shadow

Tags: html, css, z-index, box-shadow

I have a table, and I want to set some styling when you hover a row, so I used `box-shadow`, and added the corresponding z-index to make this work. The problem is that when I set the `td`s to have a background color, it just makes it be on top of  the box-shadow, and therefore the hover does not work.

**How can I fix this so that I can have both a background-color in the `td` elements, and do the box-shadow style when hovering on a row?**

I reproduced it in this simple jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/pjz43a52/

Check that when you hover on a row, the box-shadow is behind the other rows. If you comment the line for the `td` background-color, it just works:

```
table td {
  /* background-color: #EFEFEF; */
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Any ideas why would this happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Box Shadow on table row not appearing on certain browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874985/box-shadow-on-table-row-not-appearing-on-certain-browsers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because `td` is a child of `tr`. When your CSS sets `tr` to have a higher z-index than `td` on hover, it will be rendered above the surrounding cells so you can see the shadow cast on its neighbours. However no shadow can be cast on its own child `td` as they are also raised with their parent.

You need to set your parent row to appear above its own children. One way you might achieve this is by setting `td` z-index to -1 and removing all z-indexes from `tr`. Doing this does make the row's shadow to display over top of all cells, including its own children, but in both Chrome and Firefox the rendering is awful.

To get this to work you must also ensure that *every* element affected by a z-index change has its `position` property set to non static.

```
table tr {
  position: relative;
}

table td {
  position:relative;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  z-index: -1;
}

table tr:hover {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 
    inset 5px 0 0 #dadce0, 
    inset -3px 0 0 #dadce0, 
    0 5px 2px 0 rgba(60,64,67,.3), 
    0 5px 3px 1px rgba(60,64,67,.15);
}
```

Comment: I am having a different problem now, it seems that when the table is inside a div that has a background color, the tds are not visible. Check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/pjz43a52/5/

Comment: @PabloMatiasGomez this is because the `td`s have a z-index of -1 so they are being rendered below the container div. To fix this you must give both your container div and your `<table>` element `position: relative`, and set `.container` to have a z-index of 0 and `<table>` to have a z-index of 1. These z-indexes will force the table and its children to render above the container. The `td`'s index will still be below the row, but it will now be displayed above the container.