# bottom shadow of row is not displaying when hovered over row?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have used datatable,

when i hovered over row bottom shadow is not displaying , why? only right and left shadow is displayed.

```
  table.dataTable tbody tr:hover {
                    
                   background-color: #fbfbfb; box-shadow: 0px 2px 18px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); cursor: pointer; 
                   border-bottom:double;
                }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXZP8.png)

Comment: I think it is because you are applying the shadow in the `tr` and the shadow is behind the next `tr`. Do you get the same result if you hover in the last `tr` you have?

Comment: haha tr must be linline then, so just set it to display:block;

Comment: why dont you use css grid dude ?

Comment: @Julio, in the last row , i can see shadow, but not in middle of row

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Box Shadow on table row not appearing on certain browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874985/box-shadow-on-table-row-not-appearing-on-certain-browsers)

Comment: I've created a codepen as an example using your code and the answer supplied above. View [here](https://codepen.io/brayden-merrifield/pen/gOPVrwr)

Answer (score 0):

Try positioning the rows relative, setting the display to block and setting the z-index in tr:hover to bring the current table row to the front.
E.g.:

```
table tbody tr:hover {
background-color:#13326b;
color:#ffffff;
text-shadow: 1px 2px #000000;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ff0000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ff0000;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ff0000;
z-index:100;
}
td, th { padding-left: 16px; min-width: 170px;  text-align: left; }
table tbody tr , table tbody td{
    height:100px;
}
tr{
  display: block;
  position:relative;
  background-color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: i got shadow but , ui is disguised

Comment: @pratik Try setting the z-Index of the ui to a greater value than the tr:hover z-index

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kX3YP.png)

```
 table.dataTable { 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}

 table.dataTable td, th { 
  width:100%
}

  table.dataTable tr {
  display: block; 

}
   table.dataTable tr:hover {     
  position: relative; 
  background-color: orange;  
  cursor: pointer; 
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 18px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
  cursor: pointer; 
}
```

i got shadow using above code but, ui is disguised.

Comment: @ChewySalmon , i have used above code  , i got shadow but ui id disguised