# `box-shadow` doesn't work in Chrome in combination with `border-collapse` and `position: relative`

Tags: css, html-table, css-position, border-collapse

I have a `<table>` with data. For style reasons, it has `border-collapse`.

In that table, the `<td>` elements have `position: relative` because I want them to have a tooltip (which I achieve via a child `<div>` with `position: absolute`).

In Chrome, `box-shadow` for the `<td>` doesn't work unless I delete `border-collapse` or `position: relative` (which I don't want to delete because I need them for the aforementioned reasons). How can I fix that? It works fine in Firefox.

Here's a small example:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>This has a shadow in Firefox but not in Chrome</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

For people who question `position: relative`, here's a longer example where removing `position: relative` breaks the desired functionality of the tooltip:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ff5555;
  z-index: 1000;
  right: 0; /* -1px looks inconsistent across columns :( */
  top: 100%; /* pixel-perfect */
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td:hover>div {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Hover your mouse cursor here
      <div>tooltip</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Shadow is missing in Chrome</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What happens when you set `display: inline-block;` for the <td>s?

Comment: @Luckyfella Setting `display: inline-block;` for the `<td>`s fixes the shadows (I wonder why) but breaks the table layout: cells of the same column have different widths and x-coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with the combination of `border-collapse`, `position: relative`, and `box-shadow` in Chrome.

Original solution

1. [Box Shadow on table row not appearing on certain browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874985/box-shadow-on-table-row-not-appearing-on-certain-browsers)

Here’s how you can modify your CSS:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
  transform: scale(1);
}

div {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ff5555;
  z-index: 1000;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td:hover>div {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: I combined your CSS code with my second HTML example, but I still don't see a shadow. I'll look at the link you posted.