# Creating a "sunken" effect

Tags: css

The attached figure has an effect that makes the box look like it has a thickness of about a page and it's sitting on the surface.  All four sides look like they're raised.  I'm looking for the opposite effect that would make the box look like it's "sunken" by about a page thickness.

Thanks for any ideas.[image]

Comment: Why down vote and then not provide any indication as to what is wrong with the question? Without conveying any information, nobody knows what you are thinking...

Comment: Whoever downvoted the question seems to think there's an obvious and trivial solution to this.  There isn't.  Imagine a cutout in the box above where you can see the surface below and feel the height of the box around the cutout on all four sides. That's the effect I'm looking for.

Comment: Could you provide an image of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Here's something I did with Fireworks - http://jsfiddle.net/mfsU5/. The image on the left is the best I could do with CSS3.  Even the Fireworks image isn't exactly what I want because it shows the light coming from the upper left, so the right and bottom edges are lighter. I'd like all four edges to be dark,  like the upper and left edge, as if the light was directly overhead.  The Fireworks image, though, definitely gives me the feeling of a depth, as if the inner rectangle was cut out of a 1/16 inch mat. That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Site http://css-shack.herokuapp.com/ is absolutely for you!

Answer (score 13):

I think really you just want to add 'inset' to your box-shadow rule. See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp for more details.

Something like:

```
box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #555 inset;
```

So for your example, http://jsfiddle.net/FY2mk/ works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a thought:

```html
<div
  style="
    box-shadow: inset 2px 5px 20px #555;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 5px;
  "
>
  <div
    style="
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background: #f00;
      box-shadow: inset 0px -10px 25px #700, 0px 5px 5px #333;
      margin: 20px 30px;
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      border-radius: 5px;
    "
  >
    page
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sK5bB/80/

You can achieve quite a lot if you play around with the box-shadow parameters.

Comment: Brrr. Inline css. JSFiddle has a CSS window, use it.

Comment: That's a nice effect but it's not the "step" dropdown I'm looking for.  A decent example is on jsfiddle when you load it.  It has that "cloud" image that looks like it's sunken, at least on the top half,  from the surroundings.

Comment: I've updated it again.  http://jsfiddle.net/itsmikem/QDMpr/
If you want artwork that's embossed, you'll probably want to go with an image.  If it's just text, you can get a half-way decent emboss with a combination of text-shadow and box-shadow.  There is a not well supported css emboss filter as well.

Answer (score 1):

Sunken thing? I would image you are trying to get a pressing effect, like the element is getting inside.

For that you might consider using inset, that's a shadow property which would make the browser give an effect to the element, and will make it feel sunken.

```
div {
 box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px #999;
}
```

Just add the inset, and it will feel sunken!

Here is a jsfiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/jfRDA/

And here is an image[image]

You can add the shadow effect as much as you want! :)

Comment: I've played with the inset effect and, like yours does, it always gives me the impression of a raised surface with smooth, rounded edges, like a the top of a loaf of bread.

Comment: You might be using `border-radius` because of rounded edges! or you might be using too much of the third parameter.

Comment: You might be using something that's causing the issue, why don't you give some jsfiddle :)

Answer (score 1):

A sunken effect of a rectangle is created by having its top/left sides have a darker edge and the bottom/right sides a lighter one.

So this one is tricky because you need 4 separate inset shadows on all four edges (or 2 if you combine top-right and bottom-left), with a colour determined per side. Luckily Alan Jereb commented [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6671887/1467194) a way to achieve just that.

Here's my example using 4 inset box-shadows that each target a side:

```css
.hard-shadow-2px {
  /* top, right, bottom, left */
  box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 0px -1px #000,
              inset -3px 0px 0px -1px #fff,
              inset 0px -3px 0px -1px #fff,
              inset 3px 0px 0px -1px #000;
  /* or merged top-left, bottom-right */
  box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 0px -1px #000,
              inset -3px -3px 0px -1px #fff;
}
.hard-shadow-5px {
  /* top, right, bottom, left */
  box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 0px -5px #000,
              inset -10px 0px 0px -5px #fff,
              inset 0px -10px 0px -5px #fff,
              inset 10px 0px 0px -5px #000;
  /* or merged top-left, bottom-right */
  box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 0px -5px #000,
              inset -10px -10px 0px -5px #fff;
}
.soft-shadow-2px {
  /* top, right, bottom, left */
  box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 3px -2px #000,
              inset -4px 0px 3px -2px #fff,
              inset 0px -4px 3px -2px #fff,
              inset 4px 0px 3px -2px #000;
  /* or merged top-left, bottom-right */
  box-shadow: inset 4px 4px 3px -2px #000,
              inset -4px -4px 3px -2px #fff;
}
.soft-shadow-5px {
  /* top, right, bottom, left */
  box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 3px -5px #000,
              inset -10px 0px 3px -5px #fff,
              inset 0px -10px 3px -5px #fff,
              inset 10px 0px 3px -5px #000;
  /* or merged top-left, bottom-right */
  box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 3px -5px #000,
              inset -10px -10px 3px -5px #fff;
}

.example-top-shadow {
  box-shadow: inset 0 10px 6px -6px yellow;
}
.example-right-shadow {
  box-shadow: inset -10px 0 6px -6px blue;
}
.example-bottom-shadow {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -10px 6px -6px green;
}
.example-left-shadow {
  box-shadow: inset 10px 0 6px -6px white;
}
.example-shadow-per-edge {
  /* top, right, bottom, left */
  box-shadow: inset 0 10px 6px -6px yellow,
              inset -10px 0 6px -6px blue,
              inset 0 -10px 6px -6px green,
              inset 10px 0 6px -6px white;
}

/** the rest is just some basic formatting and lay-out for the preview **/
body { 
  background: #aaa;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
}
div { 
  float: left;
  width: 160px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: red;
}
hr, div:nth-of-type(2n+1) { 
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="hard-shadow-2px">hard, 2px</div>
<div class="hard-shadow-5px">hard, 5px</div>
<div class="soft-shadow-2px">soft, 2px</div>
<div class="soft-shadow-5px">soft, 5px</div>
<hr>
<div class="example-top-shadow">top</div>
<div class="example-right-shadow">right</div>
<div class="example-bottom-shadow">bottom</div>
<div class="example-left-shadow">left</div>
<hr>
<div class="example-shadow-per-edge"></div>
```

The four box-shadow pixel values are:

1. offset-x: positive is to the left, negative to the right;
2. offset-y: positive is to the top, negative to the bottom;
3. blur-radius: 0 for a hard edge, higher value (never negative) for a softer edge;
4. spread-radius: positive value to expand, negative value to shrink.

So you target a side with 1st and 2nd, hard/soft with 3rd.

The combination of the 1st (and/or 2nd, if you're targeting top-left or bottom-right together) with the 4th is what defines the thickness of the inset shadow. You subtract the absolute value of the spread-radius from the absolute value of the specified offset-X or offset-Y.

Examples:

- `inset -10px 0px 0px -5px #fff,` => 10 minus 5 is 5px shadow
- `inset 4px 0px 3px -2px #000;` => 4 minus 2 is 2px shadow

To create the opposite effect, just switch the dark and light colours.