# How to draw realistic smooth slit shadow with Pure CSS3?

Tags: css

How can I make a shadow effect like the one below with pure CSS?

[image: Shadow Effect]

I am new to CSS.
The following is what I have tried so far, but I am unable to come close to what I want.  Please advise how I can make it look like the shadow in the image? Thanks!

```
box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #999999 inset
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is the closest I could get : [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3N588/). I think it's actually not bad.

[image: Pure CSS smooth paper-side shadow effect]

It combines a black shadow and a white one on top of it.

```
.yourclass{
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow:  -15px 0px 60px 25px #ffffff inset, 
        5px 0px 10px -5px #000000 inset;
}
```

Browsers' shadows smoothing might differ. I'm using chrome so you might want to tweek the values to get a cross-browser visual effect...

Read the [CSS Tricks article about box-shadows](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/) to get how they're used.

For two shadows (both sides) you need 4 shadows ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3N588/2/)) :

Result:

[image: Pure CSS smooth paper-side shadow effect]

```
.yourclass{
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow:  0px 100px 50px -40px #ffffff inset,
        0px -100px 50px -40px #ffffff inset,
        -5px 0px 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5) inset,
        5px 0px 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5) inset;
}
```

Beware, browsers' shadows rendering/smoothing can differ a lot. I'm using chrome so you might want to tweek the values to get a cross-browser visual effect...

For more info on css shadows, read this article from [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow)

Comment: Thanks! I never event thought of doing that before! That's the magic of stackoverflow!

Comment: @armel Thanks man! How can I just do it on the left and right?

Comment: @ArmelLarcier, hahaha you're right! :D Stack Overflow is best! :)

Comment: @ariel accept my answer and I'll tell you ;-)
No seriously I'll look into it but that's not alpha-proof. You'll need pseudo elements...

Comment: @armel i only need the shadow on left and right.  in your example you have on all 4 sides..

Comment: You mean it's not like the snapshot? You on firefox?

Comment: Browsers' shadows smoothing might differ. I'm using chrome so you might want to tweek the values to get a cross-browser visual effect...

Comment: @armel yup i am on firefox... can you edit it so that it looks the same way on all browsers? I will really appreciate it.  Thanks!

Comment: @ArmelLarcier thanks again! but that only looked on firefox.  I am sorry I am new to this stuff so not really sure how I can tweak it myself for other browsers.  Thanks!

Comment: @ariel you should read this article : http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/

Answer (score 2):

What you want is basically the opposite of a page curl shadow. Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/pure-css3-paper-curls/) - you should be able to easily adapt it.

Here is an example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/janfoeh/2aVCP/)

```
div {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 100px auto;

    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
}

div:after {
    position: absolute;
    height: 80%;
    width: 10px;
    content: " ";
    right: 0px;
    top: 10%;
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    z-index: -1;
}
```

We insert a pseudo-element, position it below our div and have it cast a shadow. This way, you have control over the shadows height and position.

Comment: Nice tutorial. Didn't think of trying that!

Comment: @ArmelLarcier your solution is simpler while looking even better. Nice work!