# How to make a CSS shadow for top and bottom part of a div?

Tags: html, css, shadow

I need to add a shadow to a DIV with using CSS3. For adding a shadow for the bottom part of the DIV, I use:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
        box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
```

But how to add yet also the same shadow for the top?

Thank you

Comment: search would have helped you: [CSS Box Shadow - Top and Bottom Only \[duplicate\]][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671375/css-box-shadow-top-and-bottom-only

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 posibilities:

1) play with the spread property, in negative, to compensate for the blur and avoid the shadow to show in the sides:

```
.one {
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 8px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), 0px -6px 8px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
```

2) clip the result so that again the borders don't show. You will need position: absolute for this one to work:

```
.two {
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), 0px -6px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    clip: rect(-12px, 100px, 62px, 0px);
position: absolute;
}
```

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tc323/)

Answer (score 1):

You can apply multiple box-shadow by separating your arguments with a comma:

```
box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), 0 -1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
```

Comment: This will work but will add box-shadow to all sides of the div.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is exactly what you need;

```
.box {
    box-shadow: 0  8px 8px -8px rgba(0,0,0,.75), 
                0 -8px 8px -8px rgba(0,0,0,.75);
}
```

**Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ctnels/5rhe59rk/)**