# One div above shadow from another div

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have html code like this:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="navbar">Navbar</div>
   <div class="body">Body</div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.navbar {
    background-color: green;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 16px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 16px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 16px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.body {
    background-color: white;
}
```

But I can't see shadow, because body is above navbar. How can I fix that?

Comment: make .navbar z-index greater than body-s

Comment: I made a JSBin for people to mess around with. https://jsbin.com/batelizuse/edit?html,css,output

Comment: does it work here? http://jsfiddle.net/1e0vuff5/

Comment: try this http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/g3Lg7g1a/

You need to position your body and nav. Then add z-index as you please , in this case bigger z-index for nav.

```
.navbar {
    background-color: green;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 16px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 16px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 16px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

.body {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works ! Is it possible to create shadow only in the bottom?

Comment: But on the left and right there is a shadow too unfortunately. I'd like only in the bottom.

Comment: Google it. That is currently a different problem. ex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561097/css-box-shadow-bottom-only

Answer (score 4):

Add   `position: relative;` to `.navbar`

https://jsfiddle.net/mpn8r6e9/1/

Comment: Yes, that is the easiest way to do that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You add important in `.navbar` like this:

CSS

```
 .navbar
    {
    background-color: green !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 16px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 16px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 16px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    }
```