# Prevent body scrolling when pure CSS menu is open and allow menu to scroll when it spans beyond device height

Tags: html, css, mobile, drop-down-menu, overflow

I have a pure CSS menu that is causing me some issues mostly on small screens/mobile devices.

**Issue 1**
When the menu is open the background is still scrollable. I would like the focus to be on the menu, and therefore the background would not scroll when the menu is open.

**Issue 2**
On a small screen the menu items are collapsed by default and expand once clicked on to show submenu. If one or two are expanded and the content goes beyond the devices window there is no way to scroll down to see the content outside of the current window view. If the menu is expanded it needs to be scrollable.

I experimented with the overflow property but can't fix the issue. hoping someone know how. Thanks!

```css
 
  body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: serif;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
html {
 color: #222;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 line-height: 1;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Global Header
   ========================================================================== */

.global-nav {
 /*overflow: hidden;*/
 background-color: #FFF;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 9999;
 padding: 28px 0 0 0;
}
.header {
 background-color: #fff;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 1170px;
 z-index: 3;
 clear: both;
}
.header div.menu {
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #fff;
 padding: 20px 0 0 0;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px rgba(136,136,136,1);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px rgba(136,136,136,1);
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px rgba(136,136,136,1);
 z-index: 99999999;
}
.header img {
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
.header div.menu ul.menu-links {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
}
.menu-col-one {
 width: 25%;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 60px;
}
.menu-col-two {
 width: 25%;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 60px;
}
.menu-col-three {
 width: 25%;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 60px;
}
.menu-col-four {
 width: 25%;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 60px;
}
.menu-col-five {
 display: none;
}
.header div.menu ul.menu-links li a {
 display: block;
 padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}
.header .menu {
 clear: both;
 max-height: 0;
 transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
}
.header .menu-icon {
 cursor: pointer;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 31px 32px 25px 0;
 position: relative;
}
.header .menu-icon .navicon {
 background: #00539D;
 display: block;
 height: 2px;
 position: relative;
 transition: background .2s ease-out;
 width: 40px;
}
.header .menu-icon .navicon:before, .header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
 background: #00539D;
 content: '';
 display: block;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 transition: all .2s ease-out;
 width: 100%;
}
.header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
 top: 12px;
}
.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
 top: -12px;
}
.header .menu-btn {
 display: none;
}
.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
 max-height: 100%;
}
.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon {
 background: transparent;
}
.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:before {
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:after {
 transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before, .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
 top: 0;
}
.ac-container {
 width: 1170px;
 margin: 40px auto 30px auto;
 text-align: left;
}
.ac-container article {
 overflow: visible;
 padding-right: 30px;
}
.ac-container input {
 display: none;
}
.ac-container label {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 20;
 display: block;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 25px;
}




@media only screen and (max-width: 1169px) {

.header {
 margin: 0 2%;
 width: 96%;
 padding-right: 0;
}
.ac-container {
 width: 96%;
 padding: 0 2%;
}

}


@media only screen and (max-width: 970px) {
.global-nav {
 padding: 14px 0 0 0;
}
.header .menu-icon {
 padding: 31px 1% 25px 0;
}
.header-content-right {
 display: none;
}
.header div.menu {
 margin-top: 0px;
}
.header div.menu ul.menu-links {
 margin: 0;
}
.menu-col-one {
 width: 100%;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1; 
 margin-left: 0%;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 25px;
}
.menu-col-two {
 width: 100%;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1; 
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 25px;
}
.menu-col-three {
 width: 100%;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1; 
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 25px;
}
.menu-col-four {
 width: 100%; 
 margin-right: 0%;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 25px;
}
.menu-col-five {
 width: 100%; 
 margin-right: 0%;
 display: block;
}
.header div.menu ul li.list-header {
 display: block !important;
}
.header div.menu ul li.list-item {
 display: none;
}
.ac-container label {
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #636c76;
 font-weight: bold;
 letter-spacing: 0.2px;
}
.ac-container input:checked + label, .ac-container input:checked + label:hover {
 color: #454545;
}
.ac-container input + label:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 width: 24px;
 height: 24px;
 right: 13px;
 top: -6px;
}

.ac-container article {
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
 margin-top: -1px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 10;
 -webkit-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
 -moz-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
 -o-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
 -ms-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
 transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
 max-height: 0;
 font-size: 14px;
}
.ac-container article a {
 color: #636c76;
}
.ac-container article p {
 line-height: 23px;
 font-size: 14px;
 padding: 20px;
}
.ac-container article ul li {
 padding: 10px 0;
}
.ac-container article ul li span {
 display: none;
}
.ac-container input:checked ~ article {
 -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in, box-shadow 0.1s linear;
 -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in, box-shadow 0.1s linear;
 -o-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in, box-shadow 0.1s linear;
 -ms-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in, box-shadow 0.1s linear;
 transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in, box-shadow 0.1s linear;
 max-height: 500px;/*added*/
}
}
```

```html
<!-- [Start] Header Section-->
<section class="global-nav" role="region" aria-label="globalnav">
  <header class="header" role="banner">
    <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
    <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>

    <div class="menu">
      <section class="ac-container">
        <div class="menu-col-one">
          <input id="ac-1" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />
          <label for="ac-1">DD 1</label>
          <article class="ac-small">
            <ul class="menu-links">
              <li><a href="#">Link</a> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
            </ul>
          </article>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-col-two">
          <input id="ac-2" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />
          <label for="ac-2">DD 2</label>
          <article class="ac-medium">
            <ul class="menu-links">
              <li><a href="#">Link</a> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
            </ul>
          </article>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-col-three">
          <input id="ac-3" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />
          <label for="ac-3">DD 3</label>
          <article class="ac-large">
            <ul class="menu-links">
              <li><a href="#">Link</a> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
            </ul>
          </article>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-col-four">
          <input id="ac-4" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />
          <label for="ac-4">DD 4</label>
          <article class="ac-large">
            <ul class="menu-links">
              <li><a href="#">Link</a> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
            </ul>
          </article>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-col-five">

          <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn">Button</button>
            <button class="btn">Button</button>
            <button class="btn">Button</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </header>
</section>
<!-- [End] Header Section--> 
<!-- [Start] Main Content -->
<main role="main">
  <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span> Nullam velit nulla, sagittis non massa et, volutpat ullamcorper nunc. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Quisque in dui quis justo consectetur feugiat et a dui. Integer eget justo eleifend, mattis lectus dictum, fermentum urna. Integer vitae elit non sem vehicula euismod sed non massa. Sed ac lacus tempus, pharetra lectus vel, vehicula felis. Sed pharetra viverra nisi sed euismod.</p>
  <p>Nam sodales, massa non eleifend dignissim, diam felis suscipit eros, at semper diam justo ut arcu. Duis molestie nec nisi a maximus. Vestibulum in congue risus. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam sodales neque ac pulvinar facilisis. Curabitur a lacinia ante. Mauris tempus risus lorem, vitae fermentum dolor congue in. Fusce at tristique dolor. Etiam pellentesque lectus malesuada risus malesuada luctus. Pellentesque quis quam vulputate, sagittis orci eget, egestas purus. Proin pulvinar felis et risus placerat lacinia.</p>
  <p>In condimentum fermentum efficitur. Mauris non eros ac leo aliquam euismod eget ac metus. Aenean nec eros quis orci eleifend scelerisque. Aliquam finibus vestibulum efficitur. Quisque faucibus id tortor ac gravida. Maecenas eros sapien, mollis eu libero id, faucibus viverra velit. Fusce id blandit quam. Nullam vitae mi lorem. Cras vitae tortor placerat, viverra tellus ut, mattis enim. Aenean sit amet ante tortor. Pellentesque et dignissim urna.</p>
  <p>Morbi in mollis neque, et elementum libero. Sed luctus, metus a posuere tempor, magna ante tempor leo, tempus ultrices nulla est sit amet ipsum. Curabitur bibendum aliquet erat eget interdum. Duis a egestas mi, et molestie lacus. Quisque in lorem nisi. Nulla vestibulum arcu est. Morbi blandit lacinia eleifend.</p>
  <p>Quisque malesuada ex non dui dapibus, vitae pellentesque lacus hendrerit. Pellentesque euismod id elit non auctor. Sed tempus cursus vulputate. Praesent posuere ligula nunc. Fusce libero tellus, semper in justo fringilla, dignissim accumsan nulla. Nunc semper magna metus, sit amet vehicula urna aliquet id. Donec urna sem, pellentesque id justo a, rutrum maximus dui. Fusce vel condimentum purus. Vestibulum ultricies, massa eget aliquet imperdiet, orci quam luctus ante, in ornare tortor dui at lectus. Vivamus eget luctus felis. Sed pretium ornare vulputate. Nam in vulputate nisi. Fusce magna nibh, placerat et nulla eu, vulputate posuere sapien. Suspendisse sagittis enim ut semper efficitur. Fusce dignissim enim sed magna gravida, et pretium erat ultrices. Nulla dui augue, scelerisque vel leo nec, tempor auctor purus. </p>
  <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span> Nullam velit nulla, sagittis non massa et, volutpat ullamcorper nunc. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Quisque in dui quis justo consectetur feugiat et a dui. Integer eget justo eleifend, mattis lectus dictum, fermentum urna. Integer vitae elit non sem vehicula euismod sed non massa. Sed ac lacus tempus, pharetra lectus vel, vehicula felis. Sed pharetra viverra nisi sed euismod.</p>
  <p>Nam sodales, massa non eleifend dignissim, diam felis suscipit eros, at semper diam justo ut arcu. Duis molestie nec nisi a maximus. Vestibulum in congue risus. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam sodales neque ac pulvinar facilisis. Curabitur a lacinia ante. Mauris tempus risus lorem, vitae fermentum dolor congue in. Fusce at tristique dolor. Etiam pellentesque lectus malesuada risus malesuada luctus. Pellentesque quis quam vulputate, sagittis orci eget, egestas purus. Proin pulvinar felis et risus placerat lacinia.</p>
  <p>In condimentum fermentum efficitur. Mauris non eros ac leo aliquam euismod eget ac metus. Aenean nec eros quis orci eleifend scelerisque. Aliquam finibus vestibulum efficitur. Quisque faucibus id tortor ac gravida. Maecenas eros sapien, mollis eu libero id, faucibus viverra velit. Fusce id blandit quam. Nullam vitae mi lorem. Cras vitae tortor placerat, viverra tellus ut, mattis enim. Aenean sit amet ante tortor. Pellentesque et dignissim urna.</p>
  <p>Morbi in mollis neque, et elementum libero. Sed luctus, metus a posuere tempor, magna ante tempor leo, tempus ultrices nulla est sit amet ipsum. Curabitur bibendum aliquet erat eget interdum. Duis a egestas mi, et molestie lacus. Quisque in lorem nisi. Nulla vestibulum arcu est. Morbi blandit lacinia eleifend.</p>
  <p>Quisque malesuada ex non dui dapibus, vitae pellentesque lacus hendrerit. Pellentesque euismod id elit non auctor. Sed tempus cursus vulputate. Praesent posuere ligula nunc. Fusce libero tellus, semper in justo fringilla, dignissim accumsan nulla. Nunc semper magna metus, sit amet vehicula urna aliquet id. Donec urna sem, pellentesque id justo a, rutrum maximus dui. Fusce vel condimentum purus. Vestibulum ultricies, massa eget aliquet imperdiet, orci quam luctus ante, in ornare tortor dui at lectus. Vivamus eget luctus felis. Sed pretium ornare vulputate. Nam in vulputate nisi. Fusce magna nibh, placerat et nulla eu, vulputate posuere sapien. Suspendisse sagittis enim ut semper efficitur. Fusce dignissim enim sed magna gravida, et pretium erat ultrices. Nulla dui augue, scelerisque vel leo nec, tempor auctor purus. </p>
    <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span> Nullam velit nulla, sagittis non massa et, volutpat ullamcorper nunc. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Quisque in dui quis justo consectetur feugiat et a dui. Integer eget justo eleifend, mattis lectus dictum, fermentum urna. Integer vitae elit non sem vehicula euismod sed non massa. Sed ac lacus tempus, pharetra lectus vel, vehicula felis. Sed pharetra viverra nisi sed euismod.</p>
  <p>Nam sodales, massa non eleifend dignissim, diam felis suscipit eros, at semper diam justo ut arcu. Duis molestie nec nisi a maximus. Vestibulum in congue risus. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam sodales neque ac pulvinar facilisis. Curabitur a lacinia ante. Mauris tempus risus lorem, vitae fermentum dolor congue in. Fusce at tristique dolor. Etiam pellentesque lectus malesuada risus malesuada luctus. Pellentesque quis quam vulputate, sagittis orci eget, egestas purus. Proin pulvinar felis et risus placerat lacinia.</p>
  <p>In condimentum fermentum efficitur. Mauris non eros ac leo aliquam euismod eget ac metus. Aenean nec eros quis orci eleifend scelerisque. Aliquam finibus vestibulum efficitur. Quisque faucibus id tortor ac gravida. Maecenas eros sapien, mollis eu libero id, faucibus viverra velit. Fusce id blandit quam. Nullam vitae mi lorem. Cras vitae tortor placerat, viverra tellus ut, mattis enim. Aenean sit amet ante tortor. Pellentesque et dignissim urna.</p>
  <p>Morbi in mollis neque, et elementum libero. Sed luctus, metus a posuere tempor, magna ante tempor leo, tempus ultrices nulla est sit amet ipsum. Curabitur bibendum aliquet erat eget interdum. Duis a egestas mi, et molestie lacus. Quisque in lorem nisi. Nulla vestibulum arcu est. Morbi blandit lacinia eleifend.</p>
  <p>Quisque malesuada ex non dui dapibus, vitae pellentesque lacus hendrerit. Pellentesque euismod id elit non auctor. Sed tempus cursus vulputate. Praesent posuere ligula nunc. Fusce libero tellus, semper in justo fringilla, dignissim accumsan nulla. Nunc semper magna metus, sit amet vehicula urna aliquet id. Donec urna sem, pellentesque id justo a, rutrum maximus dui. Fusce vel condimentum purus. Vestibulum ultricies, massa eget aliquet imperdiet, orci quam luctus ante, in ornare tortor dui at lectus. Vivamus eget luctus felis. Sed pretium ornare vulputate. Nam in vulputate nisi. Fusce magna nibh, placerat et nulla eu, vulputate posuere sapien. Suspendisse sagittis enim ut semper efficitur. Fusce dignissim enim sed magna gravida, et pretium erat ultrices. Nulla dui augue, scelerisque vel leo nec, tempor auctor purus. </p>
  
  <!-- [End] Main Content --> 
</main>
```

Comment: I just want to take a moment and say thank you for providing an awesome demo that clearly illustrates your problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer:

- Add `overflow: auto` on the `main` and `.menu`
- Add `height: 100%` to `html, body, main`.
- Add `max-height: 100%` to `.menu`

Made header smaller by 17px and only displayed [box-shadow on the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561097/css-box-shadow-bottom-only). You'll have to override this for mobile devices where the scrollbar is completely removed, though...

Personally, I would just add a padding at the top of the body, then let the menu slide over the content. It would be the most elegant.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: serif;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  height: 100%; /* My code */
}
html {
 color: #222;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 line-height: 1;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%; /* My code */
  overflow: hidden; /* My code */
}

/* My code */
main {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Global Header
   ========================================================================== */

.global-nav {
 /*overflow: hidden;*/
 background-color: #FFF;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: calc(100% - 17px); /* My code */
 z-index: 9999;
 padding: 28px 0 0 0;
}
.header {
 background-color: #fff;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 1170px;
 z-index: 3;
 clear: both;
}
.header div.menu {
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #fff;
 padding: 20px 0 0 0;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 3px -3px rgba(136,136,136,1); /* My code */
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 3px -3px rgba(136,136,136,1); /* My code */
 box-shadow: 0px 5px 3px -3px rgba(136,136,136,1); /* My code */
 z-index: 99999999;
}
.header img {
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
.header div.menu ul.menu-links {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
}
.menu-col-one {
 width: 25%;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 60px;
}
.menu-col-two {
 width: 25%;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 60px;
}
.menu-col-three {
 width: 25%;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 60px;
}
.menu-col-four {
 width: 25%;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 60px;
}
.menu-col-five {
 display: none;
}
.header div.menu ul.menu-links li a {
 display: block;
 padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}
.header .menu {
 clear: both;
 max-height: 0;
 transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
 width: calc(100% - 17px); /* My code */
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
}
.header .menu-icon {
 cursor: pointer;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 31px 32px 25px 0;
 position: relative;
}
.header .menu-icon .navicon {
 background: #00539D;
 display: block;
 height: 2px;
 position: relative;
 transition: background .2s ease-out;
 width: 40px;
}
.header .menu-icon .navicon:before, .header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
 background: #00539D;
 content: '';
 display: block;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 transition: all .2s ease-out;
 width: 100%;
}
.header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
 top: 12px;
}
.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
 top: -12px;
}
.header .menu-btn {
 display: none;
}
.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
  max-height: calc(100% - 20px); /* My code */
  overflow: auto; /* My code */
}
.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon {
 background: transparent;
}
.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:before {
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:after {
 transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before, .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
 top: 0;
}
.ac-container {
 width: 1170px;
 margin: 40px auto 30px auto;
 text-align: left;
}
.ac-container article {
 overflow: visible;
 padding-right: 30px;
}
.ac-container input {
 display: none;
}
.ac-container label {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 20;
 display: block;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 25px;
}




@media only screen and (max-width: 1169px) {

.header {
 margin: 0 2%;
 width: 96%;
 padding-right: 0;
}
.ac-container {
 width: 96%;
 padding: 0 2%;
}

}


@media only screen and (max-width: 970px) {
.global-nav {
 padding: 14px 0 0 0;
}
.header .menu-icon {
 padding: 31px 1% 25px 0;
}
.header-content-right {
 display: none;
}
.header div.menu {
 margin-top: 0px;
}
.header div.menu ul.menu-links {
 margin: 0;
}
.menu-col-one {
 width: 100%;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1; 
 margin-left: 0%;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 25px;
}
.menu-col-two {
 width: 100%;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1; 
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 25px;
}
.menu-col-three {
 width: 100%;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1; 
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 25px;
}
.menu-col-four {
 width: 100%; 
 margin-right: 0%;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 25px;
}
.menu-col-five {
 width: 100%; 
 margin-right: 0%;
 display: block;
}
.header div.menu ul li.list-header {
 display: block !important;
}
.header div.menu ul li.list-item {
 display: none;
}
.ac-container label {
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #636c76;
 font-weight: bold;
 letter-spacing: 0.2px;
}
.ac-container input:checked + label, .ac-container input:checked + label:hover {
 color: #454545;
}
.ac-container input + label:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 width: 24px;
 height: 24px;
 right: 13px;
 top: -6px;
}

.ac-container article {
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
 margin-top: -1px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 10;
 -webkit-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
 -moz-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
 -o-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
 -ms-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
 transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
 max-height: 0;
 font-size: 14px;
}
.ac-container article a {
 color: #636c76;
}
.ac-container article p {
 line-height: 23px;
 font-size: 14px;
 padding: 20px;
}
.ac-container article ul li {
 padding: 10px 0;
}
.ac-container article ul li span {
 display: none;
}
.ac-container input:checked ~ article {
 -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in, box-shadow 0.1s linear;
 -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in, box-shadow 0.1s linear;
 -o-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in, box-shadow 0.1s linear;
 -ms-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in, box-shadow 0.1s linear;
 transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in, box-shadow 0.1s linear;
 max-height: 500px;/*added*/
}
}
```

```html
<!-- [Start] Header Section-->
<section class="global-nav" role="region" aria-label="globalnav">
  <header class="header" role="banner">
    <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
    <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>

    <div class="menu">
      <section class="ac-container">
        <div class="menu-col-one">
          <input id="ac-1" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />
          <label for="ac-1">DD 1</label>
          <article class="ac-small">
            <ul class="menu-links">
              <li><a href="#">Link</a> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
            </ul>
          </article>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-col-two">
          <input id="ac-2" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />
          <label for="ac-2">DD 2</label>
          <article class="ac-medium">
            <ul class="menu-links">
              <li><a href="#">Link</a> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
            </ul>
          </article>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-col-three">
          <input id="ac-3" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />
          <label for="ac-3">DD 3</label>
          <article class="ac-large">
            <ul class="menu-links">
              <li><a href="#">Link</a> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
            </ul>
          </article>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-col-four">
          <input id="ac-4" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />
          <label for="ac-4">DD 4</label>
          <article class="ac-large">
            <ul class="menu-links">
              <li><a href="#">Link</a> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
            </ul>
          </article>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-col-five">

          <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn">Button</button>
            <button class="btn">Button</button>
            <button class="btn">Button</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </header>
</section>
<!-- [End] Header Section--> 
<!-- [Start] Main Content -->
<main role="main">
  <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span> Nullam velit nulla, sagittis non massa et, volutpat ullamcorper nunc. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Quisque in dui quis justo consectetur feugiat et a dui. Integer eget justo eleifend, mattis lectus dictum, fermentum urna. Integer vitae elit non sem vehicula euismod sed non massa. Sed ac lacus tempus, pharetra lectus vel, vehicula felis. Sed pharetra viverra nisi sed euismod.</p>
  <p>Nam sodales, massa non eleifend dignissim, diam felis suscipit eros, at semper diam justo ut arcu. Duis molestie nec nisi a maximus. Vestibulum in congue risus. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam sodales neque ac pulvinar facilisis. Curabitur a lacinia ante. Mauris tempus risus lorem, vitae fermentum dolor congue in. Fusce at tristique dolor. Etiam pellentesque lectus malesuada risus malesuada luctus. Pellentesque quis quam vulputate, sagittis orci eget, egestas purus. Proin pulvinar felis et risus placerat lacinia.</p>
  <p>In condimentum fermentum efficitur. Mauris non eros ac leo aliquam euismod eget ac metus. Aenean nec eros quis orci eleifend scelerisque. Aliquam finibus vestibulum efficitur. Quisque faucibus id tortor ac gravida. Maecenas eros sapien, mollis eu libero id, faucibus viverra velit. Fusce id blandit quam. Nullam vitae mi lorem. Cras vitae tortor placerat, viverra tellus ut, mattis enim. Aenean sit amet ante tortor. Pellentesque et dignissim urna.</p>
  <p>Morbi in mollis neque, et elementum libero. Sed luctus, metus a posuere tempor, magna ante tempor leo, tempus ultrices nulla est sit amet ipsum. Curabitur bibendum aliquet erat eget interdum. Duis a egestas mi, et molestie lacus. Quisque in lorem nisi. Nulla vestibulum arcu est. Morbi blandit lacinia eleifend.</p>
  <p>Quisque malesuada ex non dui dapibus, vitae pellentesque lacus hendrerit. Pellentesque euismod id elit non auctor. Sed tempus cursus vulputate. Praesent posuere ligula nunc. Fusce libero tellus, semper in justo fringilla, dignissim accumsan nulla. Nunc semper magna metus, sit amet vehicula urna aliquet id. Donec urna sem, pellentesque id justo a, rutrum maximus dui. Fusce vel condimentum purus. Vestibulum ultricies, massa eget aliquet imperdiet, orci quam luctus ante, in ornare tortor dui at lectus. Vivamus eget luctus felis. Sed pretium ornare vulputate. Nam in vulputate nisi. Fusce magna nibh, placerat et nulla eu, vulputate posuere sapien. Suspendisse sagittis enim ut semper efficitur. Fusce dignissim enim sed magna gravida, et pretium erat ultrices. Nulla dui augue, scelerisque vel leo nec, tempor auctor purus. </p>
  <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span> Nullam velit nulla, sagittis non massa et, volutpat ullamcorper nunc. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Quisque in dui quis justo consectetur feugiat et a dui. Integer eget justo eleifend, mattis lectus dictum, fermentum urna. Integer vitae elit non sem vehicula euismod sed non massa. Sed ac lacus tempus, pharetra lectus vel, vehicula felis. Sed pharetra viverra nisi sed euismod.</p>
  <p>Nam sodales, massa non eleifend dignissim, diam felis suscipit eros, at semper diam justo ut arcu. Duis molestie nec nisi a maximus. Vestibulum in congue risus. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam sodales neque ac pulvinar facilisis. Curabitur a lacinia ante. Mauris tempus risus lorem, vitae fermentum dolor congue in. Fusce at tristique dolor. Etiam pellentesque lectus malesuada risus malesuada luctus. Pellentesque quis quam vulputate, sagittis orci eget, egestas purus. Proin pulvinar felis et risus placerat lacinia.</p>
  <p>In condimentum fermentum efficitur. Mauris non eros ac leo aliquam euismod eget ac metus. Aenean nec eros quis orci eleifend scelerisque. Aliquam finibus vestibulum efficitur. Quisque faucibus id tortor ac gravida. Maecenas eros sapien, mollis eu libero id, faucibus viverra velit. Fusce id blandit quam. Nullam vitae mi lorem. Cras vitae tortor placerat, viverra tellus ut, mattis enim. Aenean sit amet ante tortor. Pellentesque et dignissim urna.</p>
  <p>Morbi in mollis neque, et elementum libero. Sed luctus, metus a posuere tempor, magna ante tempor leo, tempus ultrices nulla est sit amet ipsum. Curabitur bibendum aliquet erat eget interdum. Duis a egestas mi, et molestie lacus. Quisque in lorem nisi. Nulla vestibulum arcu est. Morbi blandit lacinia eleifend.</p>
  <p>Quisque malesuada ex non dui dapibus, vitae pellentesque lacus hendrerit. Pellentesque euismod id elit non auctor. Sed tempus cursus vulputate. Praesent posuere ligula nunc. Fusce libero tellus, semper in justo fringilla, dignissim accumsan nulla. Nunc semper magna metus, sit amet vehicula urna aliquet id. Donec urna sem, pellentesque id justo a, rutrum maximus dui. Fusce vel condimentum purus. Vestibulum ultricies, massa eget aliquet imperdiet, orci quam luctus ante, in ornare tortor dui at lectus. Vivamus eget luctus felis. Sed pretium ornare vulputate. Nam in vulputate nisi. Fusce magna nibh, placerat et nulla eu, vulputate posuere sapien. Suspendisse sagittis enim ut semper efficitur. Fusce dignissim enim sed magna gravida, et pretium erat ultrices. Nulla dui augue, scelerisque vel leo nec, tempor auctor purus. </p>
    <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span> Nullam velit nulla, sagittis non massa et, volutpat ullamcorper nunc. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Quisque in dui quis justo consectetur feugiat et a dui. Integer eget justo eleifend, mattis lectus dictum, fermentum urna. Integer vitae elit non sem vehicula euismod sed non massa. Sed ac lacus tempus, pharetra lectus vel, vehicula felis. Sed pharetra viverra nisi sed euismod.</p>
  <p>Nam sodales, massa non eleifend dignissim, diam felis suscipit eros, at semper diam justo ut arcu. Duis molestie nec nisi a maximus. Vestibulum in congue risus. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam sodales neque ac pulvinar facilisis. Curabitur a lacinia ante. Mauris tempus risus lorem, vitae fermentum dolor congue in. Fusce at tristique dolor. Etiam pellentesque lectus malesuada risus malesuada luctus. Pellentesque quis quam vulputate, sagittis orci eget, egestas purus. Proin pulvinar felis et risus placerat lacinia.</p>
  <p>In condimentum fermentum efficitur. Mauris non eros ac leo aliquam euismod eget ac metus. Aenean nec eros quis orci eleifend scelerisque. Aliquam finibus vestibulum efficitur. Quisque faucibus id tortor ac gravida. Maecenas eros sapien, mollis eu libero id, faucibus viverra velit. Fusce id blandit quam. Nullam vitae mi lorem. Cras vitae tortor placerat, viverra tellus ut, mattis enim. Aenean sit amet ante tortor. Pellentesque et dignissim urna.</p>
  <p>Morbi in mollis neque, et elementum libero. Sed luctus, metus a posuere tempor, magna ante tempor leo, tempus ultrices nulla est sit amet ipsum. Curabitur bibendum aliquet erat eget interdum. Duis a egestas mi, et molestie lacus. Quisque in lorem nisi. Nulla vestibulum arcu est. Morbi blandit lacinia eleifend.</p>
  <p>Quisque malesuada ex non dui dapibus, vitae pellentesque lacus hendrerit. Pellentesque euismod id elit non auctor. Sed tempus cursus vulputate. Praesent posuere ligula nunc. Fusce libero tellus, semper in justo fringilla, dignissim accumsan nulla. Nunc semper magna metus, sit amet vehicula urna aliquet id. Donec urna sem, pellentesque id justo a, rutrum maximus dui. Fusce vel condimentum purus. Vestibulum ultricies, massa eget aliquet imperdiet, orci quam luctus ante, in ornare tortor dui at lectus. Vivamus eget luctus felis. Sed pretium ornare vulputate. Nam in vulputate nisi. Fusce magna nibh, placerat et nulla eu, vulputate posuere sapien. Suspendisse sagittis enim ut semper efficitur. Fusce dignissim enim sed magna gravida, et pretium erat ultrices. Nulla dui augue, scelerisque vel leo nec, tempor auctor purus. </p>
  
  <!-- [End] Main Content --> 
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. That seems to put the browser scroll bar on the right behind the header. The full page demo you created does not seem to be working (wont close/expand menu). When I try to css additions on my local machine issue 2 still seems to be present.