# css box-shadow renders differently in ff/chrome

Tags: html, css, firefox, webkit, box-shadow

I need a precise `box-shadow` for a `div`, and since Chrome and Firefox render it differently:

[image]

I've been trying to use browser-specific prefixes `-moz-` and `-webkit-` to tune values a bit. But no luck: `-moz-` is for old versions of FF (up to 35), Chrome doesn't take the `-webkit-` prefix either, they both render the now standard `box-shadow` property. More interestingly it that if I keep only `-moz-` and `-webkit-` prefixes then FF uses the `-webkit-`!

[image]

What can I do to adjust values separately for each browser?

*The aim is to have a shadowed bottom border, but to avoid shadows from left and right sides of div*

Here is [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xWEbgZ).

Comment: Have you seen these? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952861/targeting-only-firefox-with-css and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328832/how-to-apply-specific-css-rules-to-chrome-only/25496712

Comment: why not shove the bottom shadow on an after psuedo element positioned to the bottom of the main element or use a bottom only configuration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561097/css-box-shadow-bottom-only

Comment: @Turnip wow thanks man, blazing fast! This is it

Comment: @Pete this may be a solution also but since ff/chrome render box-shadow differently - it needs to be adjusted anyway

Comment: Seems to render these 2 in exactly the same way: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QmKbzK - bottom only border in both ff and chrome (and ie and edge)

Comment: @Pete sadly it's different in ff/chrome on my mac