# Box-shadow on absolute positioned div with no content?

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV that I'm using as a "separator".

**Requirements:**

- That separator should be placed on the bottom of the header.
- I need that separator to span across the full viewport width.
- I need to style it using `box-shadow` on it.

**Problems:**

- I have an outer Layout DIV that limits everything to `max-width = 500px;`
- My header is not `fixed` (it's sticky, so it only becomes `fixed` after some scroll). It starts as `relative`, so I can `absolute` position the separator.
- I had to make the separator DIV with `position: absolute` and `width: 100vw` so make it span the full viewport with.

**QUESTION**

- It works as intended if I use the `border-bottom` property. It spans the full width of the viewport (1st snippet).
- But it doesn't work with `box-shadow` (nothing is displayed. 2nd snippet). Why? Is it possible to make it work with `box-shadow` in this situation?

**SNIPPET:** works with `border-bottom`

```css
.layout {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

.header {
  height: 120px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: relative;
}

.separator {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 3px;
  top: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  /*box-shadow: 0 4px 3px -3px black;*/
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.main {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="header">
    Header
    <div class="separator"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    Main
  </div>
</div>
```

**SNIPPET:** does NOT work with `box-shadow`

```css
.layout {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

.header {
  height: 120px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: relative;
}

.separator {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 3px;
  top: 100%;
  /*border-bottom: 1px solid black;*/
  box-shadow: 0 4px 3px -3px black;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.main {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="header">
    Header
    <div class="separator"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    Main
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I could set box-shadon on `header` it self.. And that's what I was doing before I needed a "sticky" header. But now my header starts as `static / relative` and it only becomes `fixed` after some scroll. When it's on the `fixed` "phase" there's no mistery. It will span the full viewport for sure. But when it's `static / relative`, my outer Layout div is limiting it's width. My plan B is to get rid of the Layout div and pass the `max-width` property down to its children. But I like the idea of controlling the `max-width` of my website in a single place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow the `box-shadow` property in that situation need some minimal `height` render a shadow. I've managed to find a solution. See snippet below.

```css
.layout {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

.header {
  height: 120px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: relative;
}

.separator {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 10%;
  top: 95%;
  /*border-bottom: 1px solid black;*/
  box-shadow: 0 4px 3px -3px black;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.main {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="header">
    Header
    <div class="separator"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    Main
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is not entirely true, you can get away with `0 height`, As long as the spread is at least `1px`

Comment: @ZohirSalak but will it spread both top and bottom? In this case I just want bottom shadow.

Comment: You can use the offsets to position it.

Answer (score 1):

The 5-value `box-shadow` shorthand you're using sets the following properties:

```
offset-x | offset-y | blur-radius | spread-radius | color
```

Your spread radius is set to `-3px`. This diminishes the "height" of the shadow to 0, since the height of your separator is `3px`.

The shadow will display if you increase the spread radius. Try this instead:

```
box-shadow: 0 4px 3px 0px black
```

Comment: You're right. I did that because I need a shadow only at the bottom part. And it was working in other DIVs. That exact same box-shadow. Why doesn't it work in this one? Do you know?

Comment: Which other DIV's was it working on?
`0 2px 3px -1px black` moves the shadow to the bottom of the separator.

Comment: If you set a bigger height, it works. That oposite `3px and -3px` it to hide the top part of the shadow. But somehow it only works in divs with some height. Try to keep my origin `box-shadow` and increase the `height` of the separator div. The shadow will show!

Comment: Your answer helped me to get there. See my answer below with how I've ended up doing. With the same `box-shadow` I was using. Thank you!

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561097/css-box-shadow-bottom-only