# Can’t make box-shadow on bottom

Tags: html, css, width, shadow, box-shadow

I need box-shadow only in bottom of block and width need to be 100%. Box-shadow works if there is width with px but not works with 100% width. What is the problem?

Comment: share your html and css code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Box Shadow Bottom Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561097/css-box-shadow-bottom-only)

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the code that is not working for you?
A box-shadow on an element with 100% width should work just fine.

```css
div{
  background: silver;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px blue; 
}
```

```html
<div>
  test
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below CSS.

```
   box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px red;
```

```css
        
div{
  background: silver;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Demo
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would make it easier for everyone if you shared your code.